# What is the correct Syntax in MySQL for IF and THEN?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

Why is my IF Statement not correct? - I've checked http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if.html, but my MySQL-Statement returns an error:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
SET @MYVAR := '9';

IF ( @MYVAR  > '0' ) THEN
   SELECT * FROM `Table` LIMIT 1;
END IF
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF - Syntax seems to complicated to me.

I've solved it with SELECT CASE.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of IF and THEN in MYSQL :

```
CREATE FUNCTION SimpleCompare(n INT, m INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);

IF n > m THEN SET s = '>';
ELSEIF n = m THEN SET s = '=';
ELSE SET s = '<';
END IF;

SET s = CONCAT(n, ' ', s, ' ', m);

RETURN s;
END
```

The error: #1064 might be showing because you might be using inbuilt keyword of MYSQL as a column name or ";"  might be missing in query.

Answer (score 0):

[12.4. Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html) - [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```sql
SET @`MYVAR` := 9;
SET @`stmt` := IF(@`MYVAR` > 0, 'SELECT * FROM `Table` LIMIT 1', 'DO (SELECT NULL)');
PREPARE `exec`  FROM @`stmt`;
EXECUTE `exec`;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE `exec`;
```

[13.6.5.2. IF Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html)

```sql
/* Procedure structure for procedure `test` */

/*!50003 DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `test` */;

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
    SET @`MYVAR` := 9;
    IF (@`MYVAR` > 0) THEN
        SELECT * FROM `Table` LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```